# QtCreator Error exited with code 3

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I try to compile my project in QtCretor, I get the following message:

14:30:27: Running steps for project study ...
14:30:27: Starting: "C: \ Qt \ Qt5.1.0 \ 5.1.0 \ mingw48_32 \ bin \ qmake.exe" C: \ Users \ lmc \ Documents \ QT \ Study \ Estudo.pro-r spec-win32-g + + "CONFIG + = debug" "CONFIG + = declarative_debug" "CONFIG + = qml_debug"
ASSERT: "fileName.isEmpty () | | isAbsolutePath (fileName)" in file Q: \ qt5_workdir \ w \ s \ qtbase / qmake / library / ioutils.cpp, line 61

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
14:30:27: The process "C: \ Qt \ Qt5.1.0 \ 5.1.0 \ mingw48_32 \ bin \ qmake.exe" exited with code 3.
Error while building / deploying Project Study (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'qmake'
14:30:27: Elapsed time: 0:01.

Anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little bit late but here is the corresponding bug report:

"qmake is crashing with "Qwt 6.1 rc3" and Qt 5 "
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29642